# How do i do an inline if statement in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have this haml

```
  %table.form_upper{:style => "display:none;", :id => 'profile-info'}
    %tr{:id => 'some-row'}
```

How do i do display none on this table if a condition is met like for example i know i can do this but i feel there has got to be an inline way of doing this

```
-if condtion
  %table.form_upper{:id => 'profile-info'}
-else
  %table.form_upper{:style => "display:none;", :id => 'profile-info'}
    %tr{:id => 'some-row'}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
%table.form_upper{:style => "display:#{condition ? 'none' : ''};", :id => 'profile-info'}
```

Comment: Or more tersely: `%table.form_upper#profile-info(display="#{:none if condition}")`

Answer (score 3):

If you provide an attribute with a `nil` or `false` value, Haml will not set it:

Haml:

```
- # substitute an appropriate semantic class name here (not "hidden")
%table.form_upper#profile-info{ class:condition && 'empty' }
```

CSS:

```
table.empty { display:none }
```

Comment: best solution, choose this one

Answer (score 1):

This way is better because you separate style from logic therefore you've more control:

In HAML:

```
%table.form_upper{:class => "#{condition ? '' : 'nonvisible_fupper'};", :id => 'profile-info'}
   %tr{:id => 'some-row'}
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.nonvisible_fupper { display:none; }
```

Comment: Note that `display:block` is the wrong display style for a table. Better to hide it only when necessary and let it default to the correct display style otherwise.